# Recoding of Gender in Stata

Tags: stata, recode

In my dataset I currently have the labels Male and Female within my gender variable.

As I am going to be running a regression model I would like to change this so Male and Female are recoded to appear as 0 and 1. However, I am not sure how to do this!

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Is gender a string variable or a numeric variable with labels?

Comment: It's numeric with labels

Answer (score 0):

You need to so something like this:

`recode gender (X = 0) (Y = 1), gen(gender_dummy)`

where X and Y are the values you want to recode. You can issue a `label list` to find out what the coding is.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that your *gender* variable is numeric, with labels. To determine the numeric values, tabulate without labels

```
tab gender, nolabel
```

Let's assume the output reveals that *gender* variable is coded as male==1 and female==2. To recode that as 0 and 1, I would create a new dichotomous variable called *female* where female==1 and male==0.

```
gen female=.                     
replace female=1 if gender==2     
replace female=0 if gender==1
```

If you then want to add labels to the new *female* variable you can do that by defining a new label and assigning it to the variable:

```
label define FEMALE 1 "female" 0 "male" 
label values female FEMALE
```

You can then test this by tabulating with and without labels:

```
tab female
tab female, nolabel
```

If you no longer want the original *gender* variable, you can drop it:

```
drop gender
```

You can then rename the new *female* variable to *gender*, if you'd like, but it's generally recommend that you name dichotomous variables after whatever value is coded as 1, so I'd leave it as *female*.

```
rename female gender
```

Comment: You can compress three lines into one with `gen female = gender - 1`

Comment: That is a good point and it works perfectly if gender is coded as 1 for males and 2 for females (as I state in my example above), but it's not clear that is the case for the original question asker, Southern Soul. So, the reason I didn't do it that way is because I wanted to show Southern Soul how to do it using the replace command, just in case gender was coded differently (say, if males were coded as 5 and females 9--strange, I know, but just an example).